# Adding a method to a constructor prototype

Tags: javascript, class, methods, constructor

I am learning JavaScript and I recently came across a snag when adding a method to a constuctor prototype. I am trying to add a method that will print to the console the name of the animal created by the animal class constructor. I am trying to do this by adding this.name to the console.log statement. However, this pass when I try to submit the code.
 Here is what codeacademy tells me: "Oops, try again. It looks like your Animal.prototype.sayName method does not properly log to the console 'Hi my name is [name]' where [name] is the name of the Animal" Shouldn't this.name refer to whichever animal's name that ends up being created by the constructor? What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: Got it, everyone. It didn't pass because codeacademy wanted "Hi my name is this.name" and I wrote "Hi, my name is this.name" with an extra comma. Thanks for all of your help!

```
function Animal (name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
};
Animal.prototype.sayName = function () {
console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
};
// trying to use this.name but doesn't work
var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

Comment: Working fine for me [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/0x0eznsp/)

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to include the square brackets in the log?

Comment: Works perfect for me, you totally got it. http://jsbin.com/yocuqaloji/edit?js,console

Comment: Does the codeacademy assignment say that it should print, `"Hi my name is"` or `"Hi, my name is"`?  It could be as simple as that comma that you've got in your version.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this then? I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out! The console prints out what I want it to, but I still get the error. How frustrating.

Comment: @Pointy, it is asking for a space in between "is" and name. Looks like that part is right.

Comment: Yes but your code has a comma after the "Hi". Does theirs?

Comment: @Pointy Wow. That was it!! I can't believe that was the only reason that it didn't pass. Thanks so much!!

Comment: please answer your own question if you got it fixed, instead of adding "Solved". This isn't a forum ;-)

Comment: @MightyPork Got it!! Sorry about that, I'm pretty new here

Answer (score 0):

The code did not work because I had an additional comma in the console.log statement.

Thanks for all of your help, everyone!